# How to pass parameters from docker to angular js?

Tags: angular, docker, npm, dockerfile

I want to deploy an angular app to many ec2 instances with different backend urls. So I am switching environments while running the angular app. I am using docker. The last line of docker file starts the application like below

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The package json start command entry will look like below.

```
    "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0 --environment=uat1 --port=3000",
```

The environment and port is currently hardcoded in the package.json. I want it to me more dynamic like passing while docker run
I want to pass the port and environment with the docker run command like below

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -e environment=dev -e  -d me/app
```

and set it in the dockerfile like this

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm start ${port} ${environment}"]
```

I am not able to get it work. can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to just override the command? From the docs:

> If the user specifies arguments to docker run then they will override the default specified in CMD.

it should be possible to do `docker run -p 9000:9000 -d me/app [MY CUSTOM COMMAND]` that will overide the `CMD` in your dockerfile.

the custom command can be something like `npm start --environment=uat1`

Another way is to use `ENTRYPOINT`. you can look it up at the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `npm start` in Docker, it just adds a layer of indirection.

#### CMD script

You can add a simple script to use as a [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) that does your Docker environment setup before replacing itself with `ng`

Dockerfile:

```
COPY app.sh /app.sh
RUN chmod 755 /app.sh
CMD [ "/app.sh" ]
```

app.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
environment=${environment:-dev}
port=${port:-3000}
cd /appdir
echo "Running ${environment} on ${port}"
exec ng serve -H 0.0.0.0 --environment=${environment} --port=${port}
```

The `exec` is important as it replaces the script with the `ng` process rather than running `ng` as a child process.

#### ENTRYPOINT

You also can use [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) to set a default binary to run. You might use this if you wanted to allow users running the container direct access to `ng` command line options.

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "ng", "serve", "-H", "0.0.0.0" ]
CMD [ "--environment=dev", "--port=3000" ]
```

`CMD` then becomes the default options that paramaters to `docker run` will then override

```
$ docker run my/image --environment=prod --port=80
```

Comment: :-  
I am getting this error As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release, which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated shortly after. To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false". You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command

Comment: That looks like a deprecation warning rather than an error?

Comment: The last line is an error You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command

Comment: when I am running using the last command I am getting container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"--environment=prod\": executable file not found in $PATH"